# Refitting SVM using scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to implement an incremental learning algorithm based on scikit-learn and Support Vector Machines.

But it seems like everytime I call the fit(x,y) function a new model is constructed and not added to. Is there a way to achieve this?

My code looks like this:

```
from sklearn import svm

clf=svm.SVM()
for i in range(0,10)
clf.fit([[0,i],[i,0]],[0,1])
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In short - no. 
Scikit-learn does not support incremental training (which in scikit-learn is called `.partial_fit`) for SVMs (unless you want to use linear SVM, and train it with SGD http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html ). In general it is quite complex to traing kernelized SVM in incremental fashion.